# How to delay the mounted event

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2

App in `created` event execute AJAX request to server to get a status. In `mounted` event App fire onLoad callback with the status to let Developer decide what to do next.

Depends on the status App should redirect user or display message. Until AJAX in progress User should see loading icon.

Here is async problem. In `created` event a request already sent and app fired `mounted`, but the request still running in background. And Developer receive default status.

How to wait for status from backend and only after fire `mounted` event?

Comment: You could use a [watch](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) to wait for the response from the `created` process.  Once it changes, launch the other one.  Finally, have a watcher on the final one to enable the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really feel like you need to delay the mounted cycle:
When looking at the lifecycle [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/), it states if there is no 'el' option on the component, then you can manually call mount using vm.$mount(el).

However, could you not use the beforeUpdate lifecycle hook? So rather than delaying the mount function (delaying the component from mounting seems like a bad idea), you return the request data which triggers the beforeUpdate?

Comment: This is absolute black magic to me, but beforeUpdate worked for me, so I love you.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple method is use `v-if`,like this:

```
<div class="status" v-if="requestDone">status</div>
<div class="loading" v-else>loading</div>
```

In js:

```
data() {
    return {
        requestDone: false
    }
}

created() {
    promise.then(() => {
        ...
        this.requestDone = true
    })
}
```

status wrap will render until `requestDone` becomes `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach to handle this scenario is to use `NavigationGuards` in `vue-router` .

`beforeRouteEnter` helps to decide whether a particular component associated to the router should be loaded or it has to be navigated to another route before the component is loaded.

`beforeRouteEnter` Comes with next handler. Only when `next` is invoked, the component will be loaded. This guard is a perfect area for AJAX requests.

`next()/next(true)` - proceed with navigation. This can be used when promise is resolved

`next(false)` - navigation does not occur.

```
 beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
    // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
    // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
  },
```

Once the route navigation is decided by `beforeRouteEnter guard` component lifecycle hooks like `created() or mounted()` can be invoked for further actions

**Reference:** https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use router in my App. It's single page (really, single page) app.

Comment: in your question you mentioned "Depends on the status App should redirect user " -> what kind of redirection are you doing here?

Comment: @IlyaManyahin you could also use ajax with promises. Trigger 2 ajax requests in created life cycle hook. After receiving response from 2nd ajax request remove the loading icon. To change the status of loading icon, use vue data object.

Comment: @IlyaManyahin to accomplish which usecase are you planning to use window.location ? are you planning to redirect to another vuejs component or redirect to a website under different domain?

Comment: it's doesn't matter for this question